# Changing src of dynamically loaded images with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, src

I have a div that is loaded dynamically with one or more images. Initially, all these images are crops.  The aim is, when a when a user clicks on a cropped image, its src is replaced by the full sized version.  Click the full sized version to return to the cropped image.  I have no knowledge of the file names of the image, other than that they are all numbers, except the full version has a "L" as the first character in the file name.

This code works, but I'm sure there must be a simpler way:

```
$('#class').on('click', '> img', function() {
var src = $(this).attr('src');
var test_src = src.match(/L/g);
var img_id = src.replace(/L/g, '');
var big_img = src.replace('/images/', '/images/L');
if (test_src == undefined) {
  $(this).attr('src', big_img)
    } else {
  $(this).attr('src', img_id);
   }
});
```

The problem I only managed to overcome with this code was, if I simply got the img src and added an 'L', after the first click, the img src was changed to something like '/images/L123345.jpg', and so, clicking it again with the aim of returning to the original src ('/images/12345.jpg') just added a second L.

I'm sure I've missed something really obvious.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried `if (test_src == null)` instead of `if (test_src == undefined)`

Comment: No - but as mentioned, this code works fine.  I just have the idea that it's a very complicated way to do something simple.

Comment: How much control do you have over the generation of the `img` tags? Can you store the number in the `id` attribute? I can think of some much simpler ways if you initially had e.g. `<img id="12345" class="class" src="/images/12345.jpg">`

Comment: Yes, I can add an id = [image id].  For some reason that now escapes me, I was hoping to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you can add other attributes to your images, one option is to store the base image filenames in either the `id`, or in a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) if you're using HTML5.
With images such as

```
<img src="/images/1234.jpg" class="class" data-id="1234">
<img src="/images/L5678.jpg" class="class" data-id="5678">
```

the following function will build a new `src` attribute required to swap the size from its current value. It does this first by retrieving the ID, then defining a variable `lg` that is an empty string if the *current* source includes an 'L', and equal to 'L' otherwise. Finally, it strings the two together, along with the path and file extension.

```
$('.class').on('click', '> img', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var lg = ($(this).attr('src').match(/L/) !== null) ? '' : 'L';
    $(this).attr('src', '/images/' + lg + id + '.jpg');
});
```

Comment: Very neat.  Thanks.  Works well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using jQuery class methods. Not sure if it's simpler, but I find it easier to read.

```
$('#class').on('click', '> img', function() {
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  if ($(this).hasClass('small')) {
    src.replace('/images/', '/images/L');
    $(this).removeClass('small');
    $(this).addClass('large');
  }
  else if ($(this).hasClass('large')) {
    src.replace('/images/L', '/images/');
    $(this).removeClass('large');
    $(this).addClass('small');
  }
  $(this).attr('src', src);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work...

```
var $img = $("<img>");

$img.on('load', function (e) {
    this.$photoImageManager.attr('src', e.target.src);
}.bind(this));

$img.attr('src', "../../users/" + userId + "/" + userId + "-photo.png");
```